# Cannot open existing Play2.2-Scala application

Tags: eclipse, macos, scala, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to do some front-end work on an existing Play! application built on Play! Framework 2.2.  I'm a complete newb with Play!.  So far, I've copied the application .zip file from the server over SSH and expanded it.  I've also successfully installed Play!2.2. and added the necessary PATH.  So, I thought I was getting close to tinkering with this thing, but now I'm running into some real issues. Here's the `play about` output for the application root directory (to give some context).

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT adamstafford$ play about
[info] Set current project to demofitness-1-0-snapshot (in build file:/Users/adamstafford/demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/adamstafford/demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT/}demofitness-1-0-snapshot 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] 
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

Now, I want to actually work on the application, but when I try `play eclipse` to create the eclipse files so I can open the app in the scalaIDE this happens:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT adamstafford$ play eclipse
[info] Set current project to demofitness-1-0-snapshot (in build file:/Users/adamstafford/demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT/)
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
[error]        ^
```

I've successfuly used the same command on a test app ("hello-scala"), opened it in eclipse and successfully modified, compiled and run it. So I'm not sure why this isn't working with the existing application I want to work on.  The existing app is currently running just fine on it's server, so I don't think the archive is missing necessary files, but it may be.  Here's the root dir `ls` straight off the server:

```
bin  conf  lib  logs  README  RUNNING_PID  share
```

I've also tried opening the application in Activator using Play!2.3 and I get this error message: "Unable to perform request: Directory does not contain an sbt build: /Users/adamstafford/demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT".  As you can see in the `ls` output, the application has no dedicated .sbt file in the root directory, even though it sure seems like it is an .sbt build given the `about` output above.  I'm a little lost at this point.

All I really want to do is to open the app in eclipse and change the some CSS, HTML and JS.  Any help on how to get there would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if I can provide more information that would be helpful.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I can't tell - are you in demo fitness folder, then you run play to bring up console, then eclipse?

Comment: this is actually what comes up when I run 'play' to bring up console in demo fitness folder:

`Adams-MacBook-Pro:demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT adamstafford$ play
[info] Set current project to demofitness-1-0-snapshot (in build file:/Users/adamstafford/demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT/)
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: apply, last, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: play
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: play (similar: clean)
[error] play
[error]     ^
Adams-MacBook-Pro:demofitness-1.0-SNAPSHOT adamstafford$ `

I'm pretty sure Ryan answered it. Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zip archive you have on the server is not the original source, it's a standalone binary distributable.  You'll need to find the original source if you want to modify anything.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case.  Thanks Ryan, I'll get in touch with the original developer.